# Retraining my davening pronunciation

Tags: ashkenazi, pronunciation, how-to

I received a p'sak from my rav earlier today permitting me to revert my pronunciation from a modern Israeli-American pronunciation that I learned as a child to the old Yekkish Ashkenazis (with the חולם pronounced as as German *au* [aʊ] and ע as *ng* [ŋ], as well as the usual Ashkenazi features). However, while I was davening Minchoh, I noticed that some of my former liturgical pronunciation was slipping through.

Does anyone have any suggestions for how to drill oneself to successfully change the pronunciation for one's Hebrew? (although only partially, I want to maintain the Israeli accent for conversational purposes)

Comment: Shenayim Mikra. (Note I didn't say Targum.)

Comment: @Double I was about to suggest that! Isn't that just the cure all?

Comment: @DoubleAA, I found that I'm pronouncing my patachim (passachim) as aw, rather than a, so more like a komotz.   However, B"H, I'm still differentiating between regular kamatz and kamatz katon.

Comment: @NoachmiFrankfurt Ok... Just do Shnayim Mikra slowly and carefully the way you want to train yourself in. It takes some time. I mean like many months before it's really natural. Also, it may take a number of weeks after you can get it in your silent Amida before you can do it out loud in a repitition.

Comment: Thanks, @DoubleAA. Now here's an opinion question, should I continue to use my sephardit transliterations? the alternative just looks too confusing IMO, but then again, that's just me (Doesn't help that I try to write it like German :) ).

Comment: I know of children who speak three or four languages. Modern Israeli, Ashkenazis, yeshivish and English. The way it is done is to treat them as separate languages and not different dialects.

Comment: I would suggest the same way as learning French and Spanish in the way that children do (through immersion). In modern Americah there are people who can speak both "American English" and "British English" or "Ebonics" and English". The way to do this is to treat the two methods of speech as different languages. The shnaim mikra suggestion would help but you would need to practice ivrit in the same way so as not to lose it.

Comment: @sabbahillel, I really don't understand your suggestion. I am fluent in French (learned in school and at home) and I try to keep it up by conversation. I don't see how this works for Ashkenazis, which by the nature of modern Hebrew conversation, is not a language of communication.

Comment: @NoachmiFrankfurt The way I was told is that even adults can learn "another language" with the proper accents if they approach it as children do. A story is told about "Captain Jean Luc Picard"  (the British actor Patrick Stewart), was asked on his show why he spoke English with a British accent since he was "French". He answered that he was taught be a native British speaker. If you constantly read it aloud, then it is like "conversation". Consider what your French accent is like.

Comment: @sabbahillel, for familial reasons, I have a prewar accent (considering the obvious factors). I am also already somewhat nimble with accents with Hebrew. When I was using American-Israeli for davening, I didn't accent the ר, but when I use it for speaking, or singing contemporary Israeli music, I treat the ר more like a French R.  I also have some experience with Polish and Litvisch accents, as well as the aforementioned Jekkisch accent in my OP. I can also, with text in front of me, use a Spanish or a Teimani accent. So in short, I really can't understand what you're saying, please post as…

Comment: …A proper answer, as I think it might make more sense  then.